# Why would the `svg` rect change its brightness when another unrelated HTML element is about to animate?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Why would the `svg` rect change its brightness when another unrelated HTML element is about to animate?

I have encountered this quite weird situation in a project. I have copied part of the code here and the problem reproduces well. When you move the mouse to the upper part of the page, the `#status-bar` would show up.

If I remove the `transition: ease-in-out .2s all;`, the problem is gone but I have to keep it because I need the animation.

I don't want this happen, is there anything I need to do to fix it? What is the root cause of this weird thing?

Just FYI, I am on `MacOS Big Sur 11.4 (20F71)` and `Chrome Version 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (x86_64)`

```js
$('html').mousemove(function( event ) {
  var y = event.pageY;
  if( y > 120 ) {
    $('#status-bar').addClass('splashtoggle');
  } else {
    $('#status-bar').removeClass('splashtoggle');
  }
});
```

```css
.splashtoggle {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
#status-bar {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #200;
  padding: 9px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: ease-in-out .2s all;
  position: absolute;
}

#status-bar {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #200;
  padding: 9px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: ease-in-out .2s all;
  position: absolute;
  color:#fff
}

html,body {
  font-family:Lato,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}

#container {
display: none;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
filter: brightness(3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status-bar">Test Bar</div>
<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; display: inline-block;">
  <div class="" style="position:absolute:left:0;top:20px">
  <svg class="texture3d" t3d-id="texture_0order_a" width="400" height="400">
      <g class="red_layer" opacity=".5">
        <rect class="red_background" x="0" width="255" height="255" fill="rgba(153,0,0,1)"></rect>
      </g>
  </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't repro on Chrome/WIn10 - so looks like a Mac graphics issue

Comment: Perhaps try `transition: ease-in-out .2s transform;` as a possible workaround?  Otherwise we'd encourage you to report it at http://crbug.com.

Comment: This is a GPU side bug, disabling Hardware Acceleration doesn't reproduce (I can reproduce when on, on the same config). Weirdly enough, it still does it in latest Canary, but with less intensity... I made a true minimal repro here: https://jsfiddle.net/z6pab91x/ Removing anything in there will fix the issue. This is probably caused by the fact the element comes on top of the svg and that the renderer is troubled when it has to do the mixing of all the layers with the filters and the opacity during the animation. I'll try to run a bisect on this.

Comment: Found it, it's https://crbug.com/1073962